# java Can I add an element into the middle of the Stack?

Tags: java

I am using the java.util.Stack to implement a Stack ADT in my program, and I am wondering can I add an element into the middle of the Stack? Like

Stack stack = new Stack();

stack.add(i,element);

I tried adding elements in the middle of the Stack It worked like this:
Stack st = new Stack();

```
    st.push(1);
    st.push(2);
    st.push(4);
    st.add(2, 3);

        System.out.println(st.pop());
        System.out.println(st.pop());
        System.out.println(st.pop());
        System.out.println(st.pop());
```

and the result is 
4
3
2
1

I`m getting more confused

Comment: Why you do not try it out?

Comment: here are the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: There's this thing called [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Comment: inherited from Vector (insertElementAt) ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thumbs up.

Comment: but when I try adding the element in the middle of the Stack, I did the code like this :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why you would like to do such operation on Stack? Stack works on LIFO(Last in First out). So  last element inserted will be on top always.**

If you would like to do custom insertion at middle or anywhere else  use List or ArrayList or Vector.